# How to configure Dynamo DB Local's Endpoint Override when using multi-storage with Scalar DB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, scalardb

In order to use multi-storage in Scalar DB, I am implementing it with MySQL and Dynamo DB Local, but the Endpoint Override setting for Dynamo DB Local does not work.

I have configured the following settings, but are they correct?

```
## Dynamo DB for the transaction tables
scalar.db.multi_storage.storages.dynamo.storage=dynamo
scalar.db.multi_storage.storages.dynamo.contact_points=ap-northeast-1
scalar.db.multi_storage.storages.dynamo.username=fakeMyKeyId
scalar.db.multi_storage.storages.dynamo.password=fakeMyKeyId
scalar.db.multi_storage.storages.dynamo.contact_port=8000
scalar.db.multi_storage.storages.dynamo.endpoint-override=http://localhost:8000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of the storage definition in Multi-storage configuration is as follows:

```
scalar.db.multi_storage.storages.<storage name>.<property name without the prefix 'scalar.db.'>"
```

For example, if you want to specify the `scalar.db.contact_points` property for the `cassandra` storage, you can specify `scalar.db.multi_storage.storages.cassandra.contact_points`.

In your case, the storage name is `dynamo`, and you want to specify the `scalar.db.dymano.endpoint-override` property, so you need to specify `scalar.db.multi_storage.storages.dynamo.dynamo.endpoint-override` as follows:

```
scalar.db.multi_storage.storages.dynamo.dynamo.endpoint-override=http://localhost:8000
```

Please see the following document for the details:
https://github.com/scalar-labs/scalardb/blob/master/docs/multi-storage-transactions.md

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer.
I was able to access Dynamo DB Local.